# Measure cycles with TI TM4C129X Cortex-M4 Board

Tags: c, arm, cortex-m, texas-instruments

I am using a TM4C129X board from Texas Instruments and I would like to run & profile C code. So far, I haven't found an easy example of how to do this.

I tried using some example projects like "Blinky" or the "Hello World" where it prints text on the display. But, everytime when I try to set a breakpoint in a line in the main() function, the breakpoint jumps to the end of the main() function, i.e. I am not able to really count the cycles between instructions.

Does anybody have an instruction/tutorial on how to count the cycles correctly?
I would like to start with some very simple code like the one below and count the cycles for the loop.

```
int main()
{
  int a = 0; int i = 0; counter = 100;
  for (i = 0; i < counter; i++)
  {
    a += i;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Every breakpoint I set just jumps to the return statement..

Comment: Sorry if the question is unclear. Yes, I would like to measure the cpu clock cycles between two events or let's say for the complete for loop of the example.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I need to use the clock counter of the TI-IDE. This should be the most accurate as it really counts the cycles of the connected ARM chip. I do not want to use the C-intern clock functions.

Comment: So your question is really how to make the breakpoints work!?

Comment: the chip internal will be the best timer for measuring code performance.  your code is dead code so you need to work on that.  and you should isolate the code under test in a function, wrap it with proper timer reading functions to get the start, stop time and then subtract.   breakpoints and host environment tools only add delays and error to the measurement.

Comment: and being an arm as you change other code in the project the loop under test can/will change performance based on its alignment.

Comment: naturally you should examine the compiler output when doing performance tests like this and create tests that the removed code is a known quantity and not a surprise...

Answer (score 1):

First of all the code provided will not compile. Put some effort into your question, and **make sure** that the code you post compiles and gives (even erratic) output you ask about!!

> Every breakpoint I set just jumps to the return statement..

Your program has been optimized out by the compiler to the simple return. So if you try to set the breakpoint somewhere in the `main` function it is set to the only existing statement in the compiled file - `return`.

Example: https://godbolt.org/z/sEvjWWsbW

I will not advise to set optimization level to `0` as you want to profile your code, and it makes no sense to profile `-O0` generated code.

1. Try less trivial example.
2. See what actually is in your compiled code. Remember that the program flow can be different than in your C code, variables can be optimized out, and the code which does something without observable effect removed.

Comment: @cooperised ok - comment removed

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer suggest your code is optimized out. So if you put breakpoint on non existent code it will just skip it.

To remedy that You can make the variable `a` non optimizable by declaring it as

```
volatile int a=0;
```

that should prevent compiler to optimize out the for loop ... However beware `volatile` can greatly impact performance !!! especially on GCC/MCU toolchains they sometimes behaves very weirdly...

Just in case `volatile` variable means that it's content can be altered at any time outside the local code (like for example from interrupt ISR or different thread) and its usually use dfor shared variables between threads